# Breaking down nested TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

Is there any tool for refactoring interface that have 'inline' nested types to separated interfaces?

I need to break this:

```
interface A {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: string;
    }
  }
}
```

into this:

```
interface A {
  b: B
}
interface B {
  c: C
}
interface C {
  d: string
}
```

So I can use also the nested types.
I have large (generated) interfaces from JSON schemas and I would like to use also the 'subtypes'

Comment: If you want to use the nested types, then perhaps instead of refactoring the generated type definitions, it would be simpler to just write `type B = A['b']`, `type C = B['c']`, and so on?

Comment: Thanks @kaya3, I didnt know about this. Where is some doc to this? I was not able to find anything.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html